# In Visual Studio, how to autoformat code upon save?

Tags: visual-studio

I know how to do autoformat in C# manually, by pressing `CTRL + K + D`. But how do I make this happen automatically when I save the file and close the file?

I want to make this an enforced rule in my team.

Comment: Some extensions provide this functionality, like Productivity power tools or CodeMaid I think.

Comment: @X.L.Ant I am checking out CodeMaid. It seems to be exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!